# Map content not visible in QGIS Cloud web client

Tags: qgis, postgis, qgis-cloud

I'm using the QGIS Cloud plugin to generate a web map. Suddenly map content is not visible in the web client. When I asked QGIS Cloud for support they are saying there is a problem QGIS authentication manager. But I don't know how to do that. This is the message given by them :

> You write that published by another device, the map works. So the problem is on your laptop. You also write that you have not changed anything. This is not true! During the Anydesk session it was clear that the QGIS Cloud DB connection definition was not the proper one. So you have changed something. Also, as could be seen from the ticket history, you had set a different authentication method in QGIS in the meantime. What exactly happened on your laptop in total, we can't tell you from a distance! With the change of authentication, something may have been changed in the WIndows Registry as well, which affects the way QGIS Cloud works. But this is just a guess. Windows often does things that are not visible. Much to the chagrin of system administrators and support teams. If you want to continue working with QGIS Cloud, then we recommend you re-set up your laptop and reinstall QGIS. That's all we can do for you.

How can I fix this?

---

[image]

this is the version of qgis. Please guide me.

---

[![version of qgis[image: ][1]]][2]

these are the images of qgis cloud plugin and qgis version. the database is postgis database.

Comment: Welcome to SE.GIS !!!
Kindly post a screenshot along with details and provide software version details.